# xhdpi is the largest density to date, right?

Tags: android

There's no such density as "xxhdpi", right? (I know there's "xhdpi", of course). I've got a partner asking for assets in that density, but I cannot find any documentation on that. Have I missed this somehow? Is there a complete list of all known density names? I don't see anything in here, xhdpi is the largest mentioned:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Thanks

Comment: Correct, afaik/have heard there is nothing beyond xhdpi. With devices coming out with 400+dpi its possible for the future but not currently.

Comment: Expect it in [Jelly Bean](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XXHIGH).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of ICS `xhdpi` is the highest density supported. You could of course name a folder `layout-xxhdpi` and put it in your resources directory, but I don't think android would know what to do with it.

(Note: I don't know if this is correct for Jelly Bean)

**EDIT:** 
From Jens' comment I see that there are constants (added in Jelly Bean) for [XXHIGH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XXHIGH) density. However, it says that applications likely won't need to worry about this as XHIGH graphics can be scaled up. I still don't see any information about something like a `layout-xxhdpi` folder, but perhaps those documentation pages simply haven't been updated yet.

Comment: Nothing higher than xhdpi was announced with Jelly Bean, although more emphasis is being put on tvdpi for google tv/nexus 7 support

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) is a handy reference; it shows all current screen densities available, and will show any new ones available at whatever point they appear in the future.

Comment: @matt5784 - correct, for normal applications it shouldn't be _too_ noticeable with the up-scaled xhdpi resources on xxhdpi. And hand-written documentation is .. well.. does not always get the highest priority when updating stuff. The generated stuff is usually fresher.

Comment: The Nexus 10 uses icon in the drawable-xxhdpi folder for the launcher icons

Answer (score 9):

There is xxhdpi from API 16 (jelly bean). You can find it in the newest version of ADT.

It seems that the dpi range of xxhdpi should between 400dpi-500dpi (I guess so), one of the evidence is that the HTC J Butterfly (or HTC DLX) uses xxhdpi and the screen is 441dpi.

In some cases, lower dpi devices may use higher dpi assets to display contents in a bigger size. For example, xhdpi Nexus 10 uses xxhdpi launcher icons.

References:

Official G+ shows that xxhdpi is 480dpi:

https://plus.google.com/118292708268361843293/posts/ePQya3KsTjW

ADT shows xxhdpi support:

[image: new layout with xxhdpi]